# NSDateComponents wrongly adds one extra hour

Tags: ios, objective-c, parsing, nsdate, nsdatecomponents

I'm trying to create a method in Objective-C which would get the total number of minutes from a time value, written in "HHmm" format.

E.g. for "0210" the return value should be 130.

```
+ (int)totalMinutesFromHHmm:(NSString *)HHmm {
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    NSTimeZone *timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"];
    [dateFormatter setTimeZone:timeZone];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"HHmm"];
    NSLocale *enLocale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en-GB"];
    [dateFormatter setLocale:enLocale];

    NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:HHmm];
    NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];
    NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:( NSCalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnitMinute | NSCalendarUnitSecond) fromDate:date];
    NSInteger hour = [components hour];
    NSInteger minute = [components minute];
    return (int)(hour * 60 + minute);
}
```

The problem is the hour component: it's always one hour off.

[image]

On this picture the NSDate shows a 09:22 time, but on the picture below you can see the hour component is 10 (the minute component is correctly set to 22).

[image]

I looked at other posts ('NSDateComponents on hour off', etc.), but couldn't find a solution that works. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Does Great Britain do something similar to daylight saving time? If so, would UTC be one hour off from the time calculated for the Great Britain locale in that case?

Comment: Please do not show pictures of code. Show code itself. Use actual examples with print statements to demonstrate reproducible input and output.

Comment: It seems that the pictures are there to illustrate the values, as shown by the debugger. I don't think that's a bad thing. Actual code is included, apart from the pictures.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Time Zone / locale might not need to come into this. I could be misunderstanding, but it seems like you are just trying to take a string in HHmm format and calculate the total minutes.

If you need to use NSDate still for some reason, this could work:

```
+ (int)totalMinutesFromHHmm:(NSString*)HHmm
{
    NSString* refHHmm = @"0000";

    NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"HHmm"];

    NSDate* refDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:refHHmm];
    NSDate* date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:HHmm];

    int minutes = [date timeIntervalSinceDate:refDate] / 60;

    return minutes;
}
```

Otherwise, this could be a simpler option, since you know you will have a 4-character string representing the hours and minutes:

```
+ (int)totalMinutesFromHHmm:(NSString*)HHmm
{
    int minutes = [[HHmm substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 2)] intValue] * 60;
    minutes += [[HHmm substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(2, 2)] intValue];

    return minutes;
}
```